# Adding callback for change event in jQuery plugin dropdown.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, dropdown

Using this [SimpleDropDownEffects](https://github.com/codrops/SimpleDropDownEffects) plugin for jQuery, when the selected value is changed, how do I add a callback?

I'm looking for something on the lines of 'onChange'.

```
$.DropDown.defaults = {
    onChange: false,
}
```

ok, what next? plug-in have a function of the click to the option:

```
this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
    // Not executed.
}
```

Comment: From the example html i see that the dropdown its a normal html select. So you can add a change event to that element.

Comment: @piraids Could you check out all the answers? If it works for you, please select it as  accepted answer.

Comment: I solved the problem so:

add in plug-in self.inputEl.trigger('change');

$('input[name="cd-dropdown"]').change(function(e){
console.log(this.value);
});
but it is not the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
$('#cd-dropdown').dropdown({
    gutter: 5,
    onOptionSelect: function(dom) {
        var value = $(dom).attr("data-value")
        console.log(dom, value);
    }
});
```

as you can see every change it logs created element from select and values of it.

Comment: Where can I find onOptionSelect ?

Comment: I download the package from link you provided. I think its last version of it. They implemented onOptionSelect callback for select change event.

Comment: oh, sure, I don't have the latest version and there is no callback